# How to suppress warnings from ON_BLOCK_EXIT (part of ScopeGuard)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

`ON_BLOCK_EXIT` is a utility macro provided by the [ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758) [implementation](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/ScopeGuard.h?view=markup). It defines a local object for the sole reason of having its user-provided destructor executed when it falls out of scope. It is defined as:

```
#define CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define CONCATENATE(s1, s2) CONCATENATE_DIRECT(s1, s2)
#define ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(str) CONCATENATE(str, __LINE__)

#define ON_BLOCK_EXIT ScopeGuard ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(scopeGuard) = MakeGuard
```

and can be used like this:

```
void foo() {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( ... );
    ON_BLOCK_EXIT( CloseHandle, hFile );
    // more...
    // ... code...
    // ... following
} // warning C4189
```

When compiled with Visual Studio 2010 the code above generates the following `warning C4189: 'scopeGuard3' : local variable is initialized but not referenced`.

`#pragma warning( suppress : 4189 )` could be used to temporarily disable the warning. This, however, has 2 issues: 1.) It cannot be placed next to the statement that causes the warning but has to go right above the line that ends the scope. 2.) As a corollary to this it will mask out **all** warnings 4189 resulting from the current scope.

Using Visual Studio 2010 is there any way to disable this specific warning resulting from just those objects created with `ON_BLOCK_EXIT` (preferably without having to alter the call site, similar to GCC's `__attribute__((unused))`)?

Comment: There would be none of these issues with a proper RAII wrapper instead. And that would also be reusable. And would not require remembering to add the boilerplate ON_BLOCK_EXIT every time CreateFile is called. Maybe one day I will understand why people go through additional trouble to get less benefits.

Comment: I would write a wrapper around `MakeGuard` that takes a dummy parameter that you could pass `ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(scopeGuard)` to.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: Thanks for the hint in the right direction. While not the solution I eventually implemented it served as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I finally went for works for Visual Studio 2005 or later:

```
#define ON_BLOCK_EXIT( ... ) ScopeGuard ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(scopeGuard) = \
                                 MakeGuard( __VA_ARGS__ ); \
                                 (void)ANONYMOUS_VARIABLE(scopeGuard)
```

The original macro did not expand to a complete expression so there was no way to append any instrumentation to instruct the compiler to not raise a warning. Using variadic macros provided that option.